# Counting Number of arrays where sum of ith row is greater or equal to (i-1)th row

Tags: algorithms, permutations

I am working on a problem where I am supposed to count the number of arrays of size $N\times M$ where the sum of elements in the $i$-th row is greater than or equal to the the sum of elements in the $(i-1)$-th row. And the the sum of elements in $N$-th row (the last row) is less than or equal to $M$. All the elements are non negative integers.

For example, $N=2, M=2$ there are 25 solutions.

The solution that I have worked out so far is that for a row to have sum less than $M$, the number of possible ways is $C(2M,M)$. But I am unable to implement the remaining constraint.

Comment: @D.W. Turns out that the sequence $C(2,M)$ is OEIS A129763. They give a generating function solution, but no closed form. Also, it happens that this is a CodeChef competition problem, asked here and on math.SE by two apparently different people.

Comment: Thanks, @RickDecker.  Do you have a link to the Math.SE question?  That might be helpful for others.  If it's a CodeChef competition problem, maybe we should wait to answer until the competition is closed.  The CodeChef [code of conduct](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/18662/does-codechef-have-any-code-of-conduct) prohibits asking or discussing about CodeChef problems while the contest is ongoing (obviously this is not binding on us, but we could look to it for guidance).

Comment: @D.W. If you're looking for my question, it's [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319317). If you're looking for the question about the competition, it's [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319271). Had I known it was a competition question, I'd have postponed my answer, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case where $N=2$ is fairly easy. For $M\ge N$ we'll have an array
$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} &\dotsm & a_{1,M}\\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} &\dotsm & a_{2,M}\\
a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} &\dotsm & a_{3,M}\\
        &\dotsm   &         &       &        \\
a_{N,1} & a_{N,2} & a_{N,3} &\dotsm & a_{N,M}\\
\end{array}$$
Define $t(k,M)$ to be the number of integer solutions of $x_1+x_2+\dotsm+x_m=k$ with all $x_i\ge 0$. The [stars and bars theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) tells us that
$$
t(k,M)=\binom{M-1+k}{M-1}
$$
Then if we let $C(N,M)$ denote the number of solutions to the original problem, it's not hard to see that for $N=2$,
$$\begin{align}
C(2,M) &= \sum_{i=0}^M\left[t(i,M)\sum_{j=0}^it(j,M)\right]\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^M\binom{M-1+i}{M-1}\sum_{j=0}^i\binom{M-1+j}{M-1}\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^M\binom{M-1+i}{M-1}\left[\binom{M-1}{M-1}+\binom{M}{M-1}+\dotsm+\binom{M-1+i}{M-1}\right]\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^M\binom{M-1+i}{M-1}\binom{M+i}{M}
\end{align}$$
The last step above uses a fairly well-known result on the sum of a column of Pascal's triangle. So finally we'll have
$$
C(2,M) =\binom{M-1}{M-1}\binom{M}{M}+\binom{M}{M-1}\binom{M+1}{M}+\dotsm+\binom{2M-1}{M-1}\binom{2M}{M}
$$
For $N=M=2$ we have $C(2,2)=1+6+18=25$, which agrees with your example.

---

**Added yet again**. For a (not particularly useful) general form, it's not hard to see that
$$
C(N,M)=\sum_{0\le i_1\le i_2\le\dotsm i_N\le M} t(i_1,M)t(i_2,M)\dotsm t(i_N,M)
$$
In this expression, each of the $i_k$ represents the possible sum of the $k$-th row.

I asked on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319317) whether the expression for $C(2,M)$ had a closed form and the consensus was that it didn't (although it can be expressed as a hypergeometric series, for what that's worth).

Comment: Answer for C(2,3) is 273.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. Can you give me the general form of the expression.

Comment: Not necessarily a general form.... If we could use from the previous computed solution... Like for C(N,M) may be we can use results of C(N-1,M)... I hope I was clear

Comment: @aman. I tried that with only partial success. It turns out that, as far as I could tell, some parts of $C(N,M)$ can be written in terms of $C(N',M)$ with $N'<N$, but not all of them.